# How do I install PHP7 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php, php7

When I try to install PHP7 form this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-cgi
```

Then I get error:

```
couldn't find or unable to locate all these packages.
```

So I want to download php7.1 from [php.net](http://php.net), then run with Apache. What is the process to do that? How to configure files like `apache2.conf` & `php.ini` to run PHP?

Comment: ubuntu version?

Comment: @Dimitar actually i am using LinuxMint 17.2, Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Sorry but we do not support Mint, official Ubuntu only. Please ask at http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 12):

You need to add additional repository, as php7 is not available for your distro version. Please make sure to clean all php packages and dependencies you have installed. Then proceed with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

Comment: Thanks but i want manually like download folder than run

Comment: @leecarter Ehm, _why_ would anyone bother to do so while having APT?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working anymore, I'm getting: `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ondrej/php'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.`

Answer (score 3):

Type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y language-pack-en-base 
sudo LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Or:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Update the package index. To resynchronize the package index files from their sources, enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**List all PHP 7 packages**

Type the following apt-cache command:

```
apt-cache search php7
```

**Install PHP 7**

Type the following command to install PHP 7 along with useful php modules such as MySQL, GD, curl and so on:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-fpm php7.0-gd \
   php7.0-json php7.0-mysql php7.0-readline
```